# Octave 3D Plot coloring

Tags: plot, colors, 3d, octave

I'm trying to color a graph so that lower Z values are darker and higher ones, brighter. Is there a way to do that?

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(-5:.1:5);
s=X+sqrt(-1)*Y;
Z= abs((200*(s+2))./(s.^5+8*s.^4+40*s.^3+136*s.^2+260*s+400));
mesh(X,Y,Z);
set(gca, 'zlim', [0 5] );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mesh graph already has the property you describe. It's just that the peak is so high, that when you zoomed in in the lower parts of the graph, it effectively looks like it's the same colour.

You can see the actual 'color axis' used with `caxis`; in your case:

```
> caxis
ans = 0.00000   422.39756
```

If you change this to a smaller range, you'll see what you expect.

```
> caxis([0,5])
```